# Google API integration error

Tags: php, google-maps, smarty

I am trying to integrate the Google API in my site. It was developed using PHP, Smarty and MySQL combination.

This is the code in tpl file:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true&amp;key=ABQIAAAApa-_0CsQNfWmVnQ4h2mGXRSBFKcbd2FMoFZy-RC-BWz26f5KxBTUIrYFSr0YlTKqtuEnx0YXSpIXnQ" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

During the execution I get an error:

> This site needs a different Google Maps API key. A new can be generated at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html.

Comment: did you actually try with a different key?

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html#Obtaining_Key

Comment: could u plz specify the error

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the API v2 which requires a key. The API v3 does not require a key, if you are able to use this API version.

If you want, try this scripe here...

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```